# Create list of dataframes based on parent variable names

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I'm trying to take a dataframe and convert it into a list of dataframes containing specific columns.

```
dfs <- data.frame(c('apple', 'apple', 'apple', 'apple'), c('pear','pear','pear','pear'),c('5.30','5.50','5.12','5.63'),c('2.12','2.30','2.40','2.13'),c('5.31','5.55','5.20','5.63'),c('2.15','2.35','2.44','2.15'))
names(dfs) <- c('apple','pear','price_apple','price_pear','ask_apple','ask_pear')

> dfs
apple pear price_apple price_pear ask_apple ask_pear
1 apple pear        5.30       2.12      5.31     2.15
2 apple pear        5.50       2.30      5.55     2.35
3 apple pear        5.12       2.40      5.20     2.44
4 apple pear        5.63       2.13      5.63     2.15
```

The end goal would be a list with item one 'apple' and item two 'pear'. The price and ask variables would be columns in a dataframe of their respective list elements.

The following suggestion only works on the sample data but fails to extrapolate to the real dataset:

```
tmp <- reshape(dfs[-(1:2)], sep="_", direction="long", timevar="fruit", varying=TRUE)
split(tmp, tmp$fruit)
```

but returns errors:

Error in guess(varying) : 
  failed to guess time-varying variables from their names

Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  : 
  'varying' arguments must be the same length

Comment: Your errors are probably due to 1) having variables which are not in the pattern "variable_time" so `reshape` can't guess the pattern by the specified separator (`sep="_"`). 2) you have values that are present for one time/group but not the other. I.e. you have `price_apple/pear` `ask_apple/pear` and then only `othervar_apple` without the `pear` group. But without an example of data that fails I'm just guessing as to how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```
list(
  appledf = dfs[, grep("apple", colnames(dfs))],
  peardf = dfs[, grep("pear", colnames(dfs))]
)
```

That gives:

```
[[1]]
  apple price_apple ask_apple
1 apple        5.30      5.31
2 apple        5.50      5.55
3 apple        5.12      5.20
4 apple        5.63      5.63

[[2]]
  pear price_pear ask_pear
1 pear       2.12     2.15
2 pear       2.30     2.35
3 pear       2.40     2.44
4 pear       2.13     2.15
```

Comment: This is nearly perfect, but I have a couple hundred fruits. Anyway to automate the df creation? say based on dfs[,1:200]. Thanks!

Comment: I think thelatemail beat me to it. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`reshape` to a long file and then `split`:

```
tmp <- reshape(dfs[-(1:2)], sep="_", direction="long", timevar="fruit", varying=TRUE)
split(tmp, tmp$fruit)
#$apple
#        fruit price  ask id
#1.apple apple  5.30 5.31  1
#2.apple apple  5.50 5.55  2
#3.apple apple  5.12 5.20  3
#4.apple apple  5.63 5.63  4
#
#$pear
#       fruit price  ask id
#1.pear  pear  2.12 2.15  1
#2.pear  pear  2.30 2.35  2
#3.pear  pear  2.40 2.44  3
#4.pear  pear  2.13 2.15  4
```

Arguably the `split` isn't even necessary for further analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the timevar="fruit" part. Where did this variable come from? It works on my sample data, but not on the real dataset. How does the sample know 'fruit' is from columns 1:2?

Comment: @Garglesoap - it's a name used for the first variable in the output dataset. "time" could also mean "group" in this context. You have variables in your original data like `price_[apple/pear]` - which is essentially `variable.type_[time]` or `variable.type_[group]`. You don't have to set `timevar=` necessarily - try `reshape(dfs[-(1:2)], sep="_", direction="long", varying=TRUE)` for instance and see how it is just labelled `time` instead.

Comment: I'm getting 'Error in guess(varying) : 
  failed to guess time-varying variables from their names.' Any way it give it a vector of the 1:2 colnames? My though is it should match after the '_'

Comment: @Garglesoap - the first two columns in your data are not needed as far as I can tell as they are just repeating labels. If you absolutely need them you could do `reshape(dfs, sep="_", direction="long", timevar="fruit", varying=-(1:2))` . The `varying=` option just specifies all the variables that have the pattern `variable_time`

Comment: I think the varying parameter is off. Where is this paramter from I dont see it in the reshape documentation. Error in reshapeLong(data, idvar = idvar, timevar = timevar, varying = varying,  : 
  'varying' arguments must be the same length

Comment: @Garglesoap - the varying parameter is right there in the documentation - `?stats::reshape` - second entry in the 'Arguments' section. I think you might need to make your example data more representative of your real data so this can be debugged properly.

Answer (score 1):

```
fnamevec <- c('orange', 'pear')
fruitlist <- list()
for(i in 1:2){
  temp <- dfs[,grep(as.character(fnamevec[i]), colnames(dfs))]
  fruitlist[[i]] <- temp
}
```

Comment: In this case it might be nice to iterate over the actual strings and hence name the list. Also the `temp` and the `as.character` are unnecessary. `for(fruit in fnamevec) fruitlist[[fruit]] = dfs[, grep(fruit, names(dfs))]`

Comment: Very nice! Didn't think to iterate over the string vector